# Google Pagespeed giving error "cloned graph missing node" in eliminate render blocking resource

Tags: styled-components, google-pagespeed

Google pagespeed is giving error "cloned graph missing node". I have used styled components to eliminate render blocking resource . What does this error mean?

Comment: Did you ever find and answer to this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case there where faulty script and link Tags - for some reason the src and href attributes where empty. By removing those Tags I fixed the issue.

To look deeper into the reason behind this error you can find the code where the error is thrown here
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/fa70748c46fc1fb4236417ecb8848f965cd1613f/lighthouse-core/lib/dependency-graph/base-node.js

```
const clonedThisNode = idsToIncludedClones.get(this.id);
if (!clonedThisNode) throw new Error('Cloned graph missing node');
return clonedThisNode;
```